# How to preselect current value in a select created with v-repeat in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I create a drop-down menu with `v-repeat` in Vue.js, and I have a current value where I need to add the `selected` property to the `select` tag. It seems that `v-if` can only be used to control tags, but not properties.

```
<select name="flavor">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option v-repeat="proposed_value: proposed_values" value="{{ proposed_value }}">{{ proposed_value }}</option>
</select>
```

I would need something like this:

```
<option v-repeat="proposed_value: proposed_values" 
    value="{{ proposed_value }}"
    {{ proposed_value == current_value ? 'selected' }}
>
    {{ proposed_value }}
</option>
```

This is the object used to create the drop-down:

```
{
   "name": "flavors",
   "current_value": "strawberry",
   "proposed_values": [
     "vanilla",
     "strawberry",
     "lemon"
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to do this <strike>that does not force me to monkey with the object like this?</strike>

```
{
   "name": "flavors",
   "proposed_values": [
     {"name": "vanilla", "selected": ""}
     {"name": "strawberry", "selected": "selected"}
     {"name": "lemon", "selected": ""}
  ]
}
```

I am using Vue 0.11.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like that:

```
<option v-repeat="proposed_value: proposed_values" 
    value="{{ proposed_value }}"
    selected="{{ proposed_value == current_value ? 'true' : 'false' }}"
>
    {{ proposed_value }}
</option>
```

Comment: My mistake was, that I wanted to put the property name itself in the tag, but that is not possible. But I can set the value of the property. BTW: If I use false it does not work properly (shows the last option instead of the one with the true), but with an empty string it works.

Comment: This used to work, but currently I can't use it because `selected="{{ proposed_value == current_value ? 'true' : '' }}"` sets the value of `current_value` to `{{ proposed_value }}` - with the braces. Without this line it does not happen. (It also happens if I change the comparison to `current_value.equals(proposed_value)` or anything like that.) How ist that possible?! I would not know how to use the solution in the other answer, because my `<select>` does already have `v-model="current_value"`.

Comment: @mate2code i couldn't tell, but try to put the ternary condition into a function. And call it with v-bind:selected="yourFunction". And you should update your vueJS file.

Comment: Summary: I had `v-model="current_value"` in `<select>` and `value="{{ proposed_value }}"` in `<option>`. That somehow caused that any use of `proposed_value` (such as `proposed_value == 'foo'`) set `current_value` to `{{ proposed_value }}`. My solution was to introduce a third value: `selected="{{ proposed_value == old_value ? 'true' : '' }}"`

Answer (score 10):

In Vue 1.0 and later you can just do this

```
<div id="app">
    <select v-model="selected">
        <option value="val1">Text1</option>
        <option value="val2">Text2</option>
        <option value="val3">Text3</option>
        <option value="val4">Text4</option>
        <option value="val5">Text5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
     selected: 'val3'
    }
});
```

So what will be the selected value in data it will be auto selected in dropdown as we set the model. I don't know if it works in older version as I have started from 1.0

note: Vue.js is awesome :)

Comment: v-model value is string. is it possible to pass object?

Comment: This is still valid in Vue3

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this issue myself. Solved it with this.

```
<select v-model="select">
  <template v-for="option in options">
    <option v-bind:value="option" v-bind:selected="option == savedOption">{{ option }}</option>
  </template>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

To apply a dynamic list and apply a choice:

```
   new Vue({
     el: '.panel.apps',
     data: {
       apps: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
       selected: 'three'
     }
   })
```

The HTML `selected=selected` or `selected` shorthand is written only if the `item` matched the `selected`

```
<select v-model='selected'>
  <option v-for='item in apps' 
          v-bind:selected="item == selected" 
          :value="item">{{ item }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Vue 2 it seems you can't set the `:selected="option == test"` as you would expect. I believe this is due to the nature of `v-model` usage. You need to expressly set your bound `v-model="model.selected"` to the option you expect to be pre-selected. You could do that in your mounted callback:

```
mounted () {

    this.model.selected = "my default";

},
```

In this example my option values include `"my default"`.