# Laravel blade option selected not working

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, drop-down-menu

I have a select option in my laravel blade that allows the user to select a single industry type. My problem now, is if the user is in the confirm page already, and click the cancel button, the selected industry is not being selected in the dropdown menu. I can get its previous value but I can't select it in the drop down menu. Here's what I've done:

```
<select name="industry" v-model="industry" v-bind:class="{ error: industryError }">
@foreach(config('const.industry') as $i => $industry)
    <option value="{{ $i }}" @if(old('industry' || $brand['industry']) == $i) selected @endif>{{ $industry }}</option>
    //also done this {{ $brand['industry'] == $i ? 'selected="selected"' : ''  }}
@endforeach
</select>
```

**vue.js** file

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    new Vue({
    el: '#regist_brand',
    data: {
        industry : null,
        //other data
    },
    methods:{ 
        //my methods
    },
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the `old` is wrong, the second parameter of the `old` is a default value if none exists, so try this:

```
old('industry', $brand['industry'])
```

Also make sure that your `$brand['industry']` contains the key(id) of the previously selected item. You can print it out to make sure in your option:

Debug like this:

```
<option value="{{ $i }}" @if(old('industry', $brand['industry']) == $i) selected @endif>{{ $industry . ' - ' . $i . ' - ' . $brand['industry']}}</option>
```

Comment: Yes I have done that but still not working, I can get the old value key, but is still not being selected.

Comment: Can you please give more details on how does your list looks like? Do you have multiple options with the same value for example? Have you tried selecting one without any condition to make sure that that's not a problem? Do you maybe have JavaScript that clears the selection after the page loads?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, I have updated my question, I'm using vue.js by the way :) It might be the reason why there's no selected value.

Comment: so try commenting out your vue code and make sure that it does work by just using blade. Then in order to make it work with Vue you should not be using blade, but vue only by setting your `industry` data property to the selected value. And you can look for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849432/how-to-preselect-current-value-in-a-select-created-with-v-repeat-in-vue-js)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I've finally solved it, please see my answer :)

Comment: np, happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @nakov for the inputs, I'm able to solve my problem this way:

```
<select name="industry" v-model="industry" v-bind:class="{ error: industryError }">
@foreach(config('const.industry') as $i => $industry)
    <option value="{{ $i }}">{{ $industry }}</option>
    //also done this {{ $brand['industry'] == $i ? 'selected="selected"' : ''  }}
    @php
        $industry = $brand['industry'];
    @endphp
@endforeach
</select>
<script>
    var industry = "{{ $industry }}";
</script>
```

**vue.js** file

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    new Vue({
    el: '#regist_brand',
    data: {
        industry : industry,
        //other data
    },
    methods:{ 
        //my methods
    },
})();
```