# Pre-select a VUE2 drop-down

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `vue2` app which I need to pre-select a `dropdown` but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

I have looked and tried everything in:

[How to preselect current value in a select created with v-repeat in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849432/how-to-preselect-current-value-in-a-select-created-with-v-repeat-in-vue-js)

**Normal HTML**

```
<select ref="courierList" id="courierList" class="form-control" v-model="shippingDetails.selectedCourier" @change="selectedCourierDd">
    <option :value="courier.name" v-for="(courier, i)  in couriers" :key="i">
        {{ courier.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

```
data() {
   return {
       couriers: [],
       .... OTHER DATA ITEMS
   }
},

beforeMount() {
    this.fetchCouriers();
},

fetchCouriers() {
    axios.get('/couriers')
        .then((response) => {
             this.couriers = response.data.couriers;
             .... OTHER CODE
```

**Tried code > 1**

Adding the below to the `option`

```
selected="{{ courier.name === preselectedCourierName ? 'true' : 'false' }}">
```

also tied without the `true`/`false`

**Tried code > 2**

Adding the below to the `option`

```
v-bind:selected="courier === preselectedCourierName"
```

and the below

```
data() {
    return {
        .... OTHER DATA ITEMS
        preselectedCourier: [],
        preselectedCourierName: ''
}

 fetchCouriers() {
     axios.get('/couriers')
         .then((response) => {
             this.couriers = response.data.couriers;
             .... OTHER CODE
             console.log('couriers', this.couriers[0])
             this.preselectedCourier = this.couriers[0];
             this.preselectedCourierName = this.preselectedCourier.name;

             console.log('preselectedCourier', this.preselectedCourier)
             console.log('preselectedCourierName', this.preselectedCourierName)
```

gives
[image]

**Tried code > 3**

```
<option :value="courier.name" v-for="(courier, i)  in couriers" :key="i" :selected="courier.name === 'APC'">
```

no errors but dropdown still not pre-selected

Comment: Why `courier[0].name`? You're already inside the loop, shouldn't it just be `courier.name`?

Comment: As Vue warn throws "courier" is not defined - Is there a typo with `courier` and `couriers`?

Comment: @kerbh0lz yeh realised and removed it. Just updated it and also added another solution i tried

Comment: Try `:selected="courier.name == this.preselectedCourierName"`

Answer (score 0):

The fix is in the `mounted` `hook` set the `v-model` of the `select`

```
<select v-model="shippingDetails.selectedCourier">
```

```
mounted() {
    this.shippingDetails.selectedCourier = 'APC';
}
```

Give me exactly what i wanted

[image]